# Is there a SimpleJdbcInsert method similar to usingColumns(), which takes excluded columns list as an argument?

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc

SimpleJdbcInsert has a method usingColumns(String...), where you define set of columns, included in the insert statement.

But sometimes an opposite functionality is preferred, like while having a 25-column table with one autogenerated column (eg timestamp set to current date/time) one would prefer to mention this one column as excluded from insert, instead of mentioning 24 columns.

The question is, is there a way (another method or workaround) to provide excluded columns list instead of included columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The question is, is there a way (another method or workaround) to
>   provide excluded columns list instead of included columns?

That you can achieve by using [SimpleJdbcInsert.usingGeneratedKeyColumns(String...)](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/simple/SimpleJdbcInsert.html#usingGeneratedKeyColumns%28java.lang.String...%29) method.

Comment: So simple! That might work, actually, but isn't it supposed to be used with key columns? Won't it introduce any side-effects?

Comment: I believe this might affect the result of methods like `executeAndReturnKey` or `executeAndReturnKeyHolder`, as list of generated key names is used in `AbstractJdbcInsert.executeInsertAndReturnKeyHolderInternal` method.

Comment: That should work. Checked the Spring src, the columns added in the usingGeneratedKeyColumns method are skipped while constructing the Insert statements by Spring. The method you have mentioned (executeAndReturnKeyHolder, executeAndReturnKeyHolder) is used for retriving the auto generated keys so that should not be an issue.

Comment: So that's a "no", then? This functionality _exists_, but there's no method that -- with no other, unwanted side effects -- purely just ignores columns from the input.